# Group by with number of records per result set in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `employee` table like below, which has `departmentid` as foreign key from `department` table.

I need to group them by `department` with 5 unique employee, There can be multiple employee in a department but not exceed 5 in a one set.

For example for department id 100 there are 7 unique employee, so there should be two sets.

Likewise for department id 200 there are only 2 unique employees so here it will be only 1 set

What will be the query to generate below output.

I have tried below queries so far

```
SELECT 
    EmpId, EmpName, DeptId,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DeptId ASC) ResultSetNumber
FROM 
    dbo.Employee
```

The above query is not working for 5 unique employee logic.

Employee table

```
EmpId  | EmpName | DeptId
-------+---------+--------        
1            A       100
2            B       100
3            C       100
4            D       100
5            E       100
6            A       100
7            B       100
8            F       100
9            G       100
10           H       200
11           J       200
12           C       300
13           K       300
14           A       300
15           S       300
16           M       300
```

I need below output.

```
EmpId  | EmpName | DeptId  | ResultSetNumber
-------+---------+---------+------------------
1            A       100       1
2            B       100       1
3            C       100       1
4            D       100       1
5            E       100       1
6            A       100       1
7            B       100       1
8            F       100       2
9            G       100       2
10           H       200       3
11           J       200       3
12           C       300       4
13           K       300       4
14           A       300       4
15           S       300       4
16           M       300       4
```

Comment: Is the grouping arbitrary or do you want it ordered by EmpName maybe?

Comment: yes order by EmpName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one attempt.

> ```
> DECLARE @T TABLE(EmpId INT, EmpName NVARCHAR(10), DeptId INT)
> INSERT @T VALUES
> (1,'A',100),(2,'B',100),(3,'C',100),(4,'D',100),(5,'E',100),
> (6,'A',100),(7,'B',100),(8,'F',100),(9,'G',100),(10,'H',200),
> (11,'J',200),(12,'C',300),(13,'K',300),(14,'A',300),(15,'S',300),
> (16,'M',300)--,(17,'Z',100)
>
> SELECT
>   EmpId,EmpName,DeptId,
>   ResultSetNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY GroupNumber + RankInGroup)
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT  
>       EmpId,EmpName,DeptId,
>       RankInGroup = (DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY DeptId ORDER BY EmpName) / 6) + 1,
>       GroupNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DeptId) 
>   FROM 
>       @T
> )AS X
> ORDER BY EmpID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EmpId | EmpName | DeptId | ResultSetNumber
> ----: | :------ | -----: | :--------------
>     1 | A       |    100 | 1              
>     2 | B       |    100 | 1              
>     3 | C       |    100 | 1              
>     4 | D       |    100 | 1              
>     5 | E       |    100 | 1              
>     6 | A       |    100 | 1              
>     7 | B       |    100 | 1              
>     8 | F       |    100 | 2              
>     9 | G       |    100 | 2              
>    10 | H       |    200 | 3              
>    11 | J       |    200 | 3              
>    12 | C       |    300 | 4              
>    13 | K       |    300 | 4              
>    14 | A       |    300 | 4              
>    15 | S       |    300 | 4              
>    16 | M       |    300 | 4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c7eaddfaffde63e9d8a631a8255411d)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
   select *
        from dbo.Employee emp
        inner join (
          select DeptId, EmpId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by DeptId ORDER BY DeptId) ResultSetNumber
          from dbo.Employee
          group by DeptId, EmpId) dep on dep.EmpId = emp.EmpId and emp.DeptId=dep.DeptId
        where dep.ResultSetNumber < 10(can change according to your requirement)
```

Comment: In where condition you can set dep.ResultSetNumber < 6 so that it will fetch only 5 employees per department

Comment: your query is taking top 5 unique employee, but it is not creating another group for remaining employee in a result set.